# C++ Registry Add nothing happen

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmd, regedit

I have admin rights on PC, windows and try add registry DWORD key with CMD and ShellExecute.
All others commands via this way is working, but not Reg Add.

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\Userlist\" /v username /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f", 0, SW_HIDE);
```

When i try nothing happens. Why?

I have tried running the above command directly in the `cmd` with success, but when running my application the key is not added.

Thx.

Ok guys i try use another way using this code:

```cpp
HKEY hKey;
        LPCSTR sKeyPath;
        int iResult;

        sKeyPath = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\Userlist";
        iResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKeyPath, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
        DWORD value = 0x00000000;
        iResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, "username", NULL, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Don't work too :(
I try this instead, but fail

```cpp
HKEY hKey;
_TCHAR sKeyPath[] = _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\Userlist");

RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKeyPath, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("username"), 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*)_T("000000"), sizeof(_T("000000")));
```

Comment: Are you sure it failed? Did you check the registry after running?

Comment: Of course...nothing. But if do this reg add command via CMD in Windows, its working..strange

Comment: It is. Let's wait and see if someone with more expertise can answer.

Comment: I suggest you add a complete program that produces this problem, in case the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Possible starting points: check the result from `ShellExecute`; store the parameters in a string and print it to verify that it is what you think it is; use `SW_SHOW` to see any output.

Comment: for what you exec *cmd.exe* for exec via it *reg.exe* (why not direct ?!) for it call `RegCreateKeyEx`+`RegSetValueEx` ? why you don't do this yourself ? your code if fantastic not efficient

Comment: Coz `RegCreateKeyEx`+`RegSetValueEx` its a lot tons of code . Its smaller with CMD. Im right?

Comment: @Bobby, no you wrong at first. at second why you exec cmd.exe instead reg.exe ?!

Comment: I don't know... I will try reg.exe now

Comment: How use reg.exe? Just replace cmd.exe  with reg.exe?

Comment: `ShellExecute(0, "open", "reg.exe", "add [...]"`

Comment: Using WinAPI directly: You do not check the result of your operations. See [WinAPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa): *'Unlike the RegCreateKeyEx function, the RegOpenKeyEx function does not create the specified key if the key does not exist in the registry.'*

Comment: `ShellExecute(0, "open", "reg.exe", "add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\Userlist\" /v username /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f", 0, SW_HIDE);` didn't work ((

Comment: Why do you run `cmd.exe /C reg.exe ...`, why don't you just run `reg.exe ...`?

Comment: First of all i try reg.exe, didn't work. And try regedit too